# Pass input data to subarray of GET or POST

Tags: php, html, post, get

Is it possible to have some data in a sub array of `get` or `post`?

Say I want input values from user in `$_GET['values']['value']`, instead of `$_GET['value']` Or in post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Instead of:

```
<input type="text" name="input_value" />
```

You can use:

```
<input type="text" name="inputs['input_value']" />
```

This way - php gets the `inputs` as an Array and the `inputs_value` is one of the keys in that array:

```
$_GET['inputs']['input_value'];
```

You can use the `var_dump` function to dump the `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays to see their values:

```
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: To create a subarray for the post values, the name-attribute  of the form input should not have single quotes in the brackets:
`<input type="text" name="inputs[input_value]" />`.